# Serializing array to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

How can I initialise and add dynamic values  to json array in c#? I want to add each value to json array which is inside a foreach loop.

```
foreach (DataRow drow in mydeal.Rows)
{
    // add json array values here in the key-value format//
}
```

Comment: you should just handle as you would a normal list/dictionary and then serialize the data to JSON. Although, the question doesn't give much to work from so can't say much more.

Answer (score 0):

For array, create an array and serialize it. For dictionary either create a dictionary (key-value) and custom-serialize it (covered on Stack Overflow) or use dynamic object, ex:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing

or just look for `serialize dynamic object json`, also covered on stack overflow.

If you have no clue at all how to serialize to JSON, check ASP/WebAPI tutorials, its full of those.

Answer (score 0):

To share my way that can use DataTable to transfer data and feedback Json format ,hopefully it is a good way to deal with your problem

```
public IHttpActionResult PostBanners(xx id)
        {
            string queryString = "select top 2 a.point,a.seq_banner  from Banners as a left join RelationCountryBanner as b on a.seq_banner = b.seq_file ";
           //string queryString = id.str;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
            {
                if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"] != null)
                {
                    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=******;Initial Catalog=B2CGlobal2010;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*******;Password=****";
                }
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString.ToString(), con))
                {
                    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    Dictionary<string, object> row;
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                        }
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }
                    DataTable xx = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializer.Serialize(rows), (typeof(DataTable)));
                   // return Ok(xx);
                    return Ok(serializer.Serialize(rows));
                }
            }

            return NotFound();
        }
```